# incorporating -xmlConfigured in maven

Tags: maven-2, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

Does the maven-aspectj-plugin have an option to specify ajc's option -xmlConfigured?

If not, what's the common practice for compiling aspect codes with most recent version of ajc using maven?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the maven-aspectj-plugin have an option to specify ajc's option -xmlConfigured?

AFAIK, the maven-aspectj-plugin doesn't have such an option, the `-xmlConfigured` is just too new.

> If not, what's the common practice for compiling aspect codes with most recent version of ajc using maven?

I'm pretty sure patch are appreciated and welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays AspectJ Maven has the parameter:
https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#xmlConfigured

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).